# Javascript context issue using Object.create() and function.apply doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, apply

I am running into the error with object context when trying to use Object.create.  This is a very simple example, but this is what I am doing:

```
var object1 = {
func1: function(functionArg){
    ...
    functionArg();
}
}

var object2 = {
func2: {
    value: function(){
        this.memberVariable = 1;
        ... 
        this.func1(this.func3)
    }
}

func3: {
    value: function(){
        if(this.memberVariable == 1){};
        ...
    }
}
}

var newObject = Object.create(object1,object2);
newObject.func2();
```

The Result of expression 'this.memberVariable' [undefined] is not an object.

To remember this problem, I thought that I could use apply to give the correct context to the function.  So I replaced object1 with something like:

```
var object1 = {
func1: function(functionArg){
    var thisObject = this;
    var functionArgApply = function(){
        functionArg.apply(thisObject,arguments);
    };
    ...
    functionArgApply();
}
}
```

Now I get an error saying Result of expression 'functionArg.apply' [undefined] is not a function.  I assume that's because object2 is using value notation.  I tried changing it to functionArg.value.apply but got the same result.  Should this work?

Answer (score 1):

Either `functionArg` is a string, in which case you have to use bracket notation:

```
func1: function(functionArg){
    ...
    this[functionArg]();
}
```

or it is a function reference, which case it should be

```
functionArg.apply(this)
```

It depends on what `func3` is in this line: `this.func1(func3)`. As it stands, `func3` is not defined.

In any case, `this.functionArg` is wrong, you have no property `functionArg` defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I cleaned up my example I think.  this.func1(func3) should have been this.func1(this.func3)  and this.functionArg should have just been functionArg